# Slice an array with round up in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, slice

Can anyone help me to transform this "pseudo code" to Ruby?

```
max = round_up(count(physical_values))
for i=0;i < max/100; i++
  part = physical_values[i*100..i*100+100]
  send_part_to_server(part)
end
```

It's a float array something like this:

```
11.05016861219201 10.350157930876776 10.550160982681064 11.550176241702957 12.55019150072485 12.750194552529138 11.850180819409616 10.350157930876776 9.15013962005014 9.15013962005014 10.450159456778692 12.15018539711582 13.250202182040084 12.95019760433388 11.750179293507244 10.65016250858298 10.850165560387723
```

Comment: Can you provide sample data for physical_values?

Comment: Could you explain what this code is supposed to do?

Comment: It's an array with  5000 data records, and i need to split this array in 100 elements of each "chunck" and send to the server.

Comment: In the future, please ask questions where you describe your intent, with sample input and output. Welcome to Ruby and Stack Overflow! :)

Comment: Sorry about that! I'm a beginner in Stack Overflow too :)

Comment: No problem; now you know. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want [`ceil`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Float.html#method-i-ceil) to round up and [`each_slice`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice) to get the pieces.

```
# Slices of 100 elements each
physical_values.each_slice(100){ |part| send_part_to_server( part ) }

# <=100 slices
slice_size = (physical_values.length.to_f/100).ceil
physical_values.each_slice(slice_size){ |part| send_part_to_server( part ) }
```

Note that I converted the length into a float with `to_f` because the result of dividing one integer by another is always an integer (rounded down). Alternatively I could have done:

```
(physical_values.length/100.0).ceil # Use a floating point 100.0 for float result
```

Comment: Tks a lot for your help !